# How can I calculate this integral of a differential form in a surface?

Tags: integration, manifolds, stokes-theorem

I'm trying to integrate the 2-form $\omega = A(y) dx \wedge dy - dx \wedge dz + B(z)dz \wedge dy $ in the set $R_f=\{(x,y,z),\quad z=f(x,y)\quad x^2+y^2 \neq 1 \}$ with $f$ a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$.

To do this I found $\theta = A(y)x dy + z dx - yB(z)dz$ such that $d\theta = \omega$ and applied Stokes' theorem getting that:

$$\int_{R_f} \omega = \int_{\partial R_f} \theta$$

I tried then to expand the expression that I got and compute the integral but I couldn't solve it. I've been trying to prove that with these conditions $dz=0$ and then I would be able to solve the problem.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing great so far. Let me use the name $\eta$ for the thing you call $\theta$, and then continue.

You need to integrate $\eta$ over something that projects to the unit circle in the $xy$ plane. So let's take
$$
\gamma(t) =  (\cos t, \sin t, f(\cos t, \sin t))
$$
which parameterizes the set $\partial R_f$ nicely, and use it to compute a path integral. You need to evaluate
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \eta(\gamma(t))(\gamma'(t)) dt 
&= \int \left. (A(y)x dy + z dx - yB(z)dz)\right|_{x = \cos t, y = \sin t, z = f(\cos t, \sin t)} [-\sin t, \cos t, f_x(\cos t, \sin t)(-sin t) + f_y (\cos t, \sin t) (\cos t)] dt\\
&= \int (A(\sin t) \cos t dy + f(\cos t, \sin t) dx - \sin t B(f(\cos t, \sin t)) dz))[-\sin t, \cos t, f_x(\cos t, \sin t)(-sin t) + f_y (\cos t, \sin t) (\cos t)] dt\\
&= \int A(\sin t) \cos t \cos t + f(\cos t, \sin t) (-\sin t) - \sin t B(f(\cos t, \sin t)) (f_x(\cos t, \sin t)(-\sin t) + f_y (\cos t, \sin t) (\cos t))~ dt\\
&= \int A(\sin t) \cos^2 t -\sin t ~f(\cos t, \sin t) - \sin t ~B(f(\cos t, \sin t)) (f_x(\cos t, \sin t)(-\sin t) + f_y (\cos t, \sin t) (\cos t))~ dt
\end{align}

That last integral's not pretty, but it's what you need to look at.

Comment: One question. I did the pullback (via inclusion) of $\theta$. So $i^{*}(z)=i^{*}(dz)=0$ , doesn't that simplify this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your inclusion map is $i: [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb R^3: t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t, f(\cos t, \sin t))$, then it's not true that $i^{*}(dz) = 0$.